# foundation grid not working in vue js template

Tags: vue.js, zurb-foundation

Am trying to loop through a list and display them in a grid with four cards.

```
 <div class="grid-x movies">
                    <div  v-for="item in filteredMovie" :key="item.id">
               <div class="cell large-4 medium-3 small-12">
                <div class="card">

                <img v-bind:src="item.cover_image" style="height:100px;width: 100px">

                  {{ item.name }}<br/>
                </div>
               </div>
my computed property is


computed:{
            items(){
                return this.$store.getters.getMovies
            },
            filteredMovie:function(){
                let self= this;
                return this.items.filter(function(item){
                    return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                        || item.cast.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                        || item.genre.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
                    }
                )
            }

        }

    }

                </div>
```

but the list doesn't display on the page but when i put the v-for before the grid the list  shows but  the cards are not in four columns.what could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your classes on the looping div:

```
<div class="cell large-4 medium-3 small-12" v-for="item in filteredMovie" :key="item.id">
```

Your code in a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/5b6zkLom/

Comment: they are still not displaying

Comment: please check the foundation classes you have added there.